# Twitter api json url for incorporate tweet information (like a favorites and retweets)

Tags: json, api, twitter

I want incorporate a tweet info from the twitter API, info like a favorites and retweet count. But I need an url of twitter API json in http format like this----> https://www.example.com/api/recent.json

I've tried different options like this:
- https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json?id=1130368961772707845

with this format It gives me an error-->  "errors":[
{
"code":215,
"message":"Bad Authentication data."

- http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=P2pSmart

"errors":[
{
"message":"SSL is required",
"code":92

I've tried a lot of commands from here: 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index

And all of them give me the similar error, the only one that works is this, but It don't have any interessant information: 
https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F507185938620219395

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Thanks

Comment: This is because the Twitter API requires authentication using OAuth. You cannot call the API without authentication.

Comment: I've searched about authentication using OAuth. yet i cant grasp the concept of what to include in the URL or how should i change it in order to retrieve info... could You please provide an example? Thanks